# Attribute error when calling an instance variable in an instance method

Tags: python, tkinter

When calling certain instance variables from any of my instance methods I get an attribution error saying the instance variable in question doesn't exist. This program is supposed to be a GUI for a quiz and without calling 'questionlabel' works without errors.

I've attempted numerous ways of bypassing this issue including putting questionlabel inside it's own instance method then calling said method from radio_btn_gen which worked but meant I had trouble destroying it on the end screen and ended up being a head ache. I've browsed through stack overflow trying to find something similar to my problem but most attribute errors people tend to have tend to spelling mistakes.

```
import tkinter as tk
LARGEFONT=("Impact",72)
SMALLFONT=("Verdana",12)

class QuizApp():
    def __init__(self,parent):    
        self.qNa=(("question","answer","answer","answer"),   ("question","answer","answer","answer"))#List of questions and answers
        self.correctanswers=("answer")#All the correct answers
        self.v = tk.StringVar()#stringVar for radiobuttons

        self.page=0
        self.radiobtnsframe=0
        self.v.set("n/a")
        self.rblist=[]
        self.attemptlist=[]#stores all the attempts made on the quiz        
        self.radio_btn_gen()
        #above are the variables used for managing the radio button list 
        self.questionlabel=tk.Label(parent,text=self.qNa[self.page][0],font=SMALLFONT)

        self.rightlabel=tk.Label(font=SMALLFONT)#Displays correct answers at the end of quiz

        self.confirmlabel = tk.Label(parent, textvariable = self.v) #tkinter converts IntVar to text for textvariable
        self.confirmlabel.grid(row=1,column=1)

        self.nxtbtn=tk.Button(text="Next",font=SMALLFONT,command=self.nxt_btn_cmd)#Changes the page to the next question when pressed
        self.nxtbtn.grid(row=4,column=0)

    def radio_btn_gen(self):
        self.questionlabel.grid(row=0,column=0)#Creates the question label in the gui
        self.radiobtnsframe=tk.Frame(relief="flat",borderwidth=2)# the frame that holds the radiobuttons
        for i in self.qNa[self.page][1:]:#Iterates through inner lists of 'qNa' list and loads the radiobuttons into 'radiobtnsframe' 
            self.rb = tk.Radiobutton(master=self.radiobtnsframe,variable = self.v, value = i, 
            text= i,indicatoron=False,font=SMALLFONT)
            self.rblist.append(self.rb)
            self.rb.pack(fill="both")
            self.radiobtnsframe.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.v.set("n/a")

    def nxt_btn_cmd(self):#command called when next button pushed
        rbvalue=self.v.get()#calls 'v' and assigns it to rbValue

        if rbvalue != "n/a":#checks to see if any radiobuttons have been pushed

            self.page+=1#increments page number

            if self.page+1 > len(self.qNa):#checks to see if page number matches the number of questions 
                correctattempts=[i for i, j in zip(self.attemptlist, self.correctanswers) if i == j]#used to sort the correct answers into a list
                self.rightlabel.config(text="you got {} questions right".format(len(correctattempts)))#displays how many answers you got right
                self.rightlabel.grid(row=0,column=0)#No issue when called
                self.radiobtnsframe.destroy()
                self.confirmlabel.destroy()#similar label with no error attached when called
                self.questionlabel.destroy()#attribute error when 'questionlabel' called 
                return #terminates method before executing the commands below 
            self.attemptlist.append(rbvalue)
            self.radiobtnsframe.destroy()
            self.radio_btn_gen()
        del self.rblist[:]#clears the list storing the radiobutton data

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    root=tk.Tk()
    app=QuizApp(root)#calls the app
    root.mainloop
```

The error code

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'QuizApp' object has no attribute 'questionlabel'
  File "C:\Users\jrich\Documents\stackoverflowquestion.py", line 29, in radio_btn_gen
    self.questionlabel.grid(row=0,column=0)#Creates the question label in the gui
  File "C:\Users\jrich\Documents\stackoverflowquestion.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.radio_btn_gen()
  File "C:\Users\jrich\Documents\stackoverflowquestion.py", line 61, in <module>
    app=QuizApp(root)
```

If anyone can spot any other problems in my code and would care to inform of them I would highly appreciate it. if anything appears convoluted or out of place I'm very much still learning and my teacher has an 'interesting' way of coding to say the least. Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: You are callling `radio_btn_gen` before initializing `self.questionlabel` in `_init_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
        self.radio_btn_gen()
        #above are the variables used for managing the radio button list 
        self.questionlabel=tk.Label(parent,text=self.qNa[self.page][0],font=SMALLFONT)
```

In `radio_btn_gen` you are trying to access `self.questionlabel` but in `__init__` you call this method before you set `self.questionlabel`.

Comment: god that makes me feel idiot. I though I read the error message properly. Thank you!